# Viewing State of Existing Deep Linking URLs

Tags: branch.io

I need to generate a link from a C# backend and I am using the Rest API.

This works for the example provided [here](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Deferred-Deep-Linking-Public-API) and it do create a link when I am using our own branch_key.

```
curl -X POST \
\
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
\
-d '{"branch_key":"key_live_feebgAAhbH9Tv85H5wLQhpdaefiZv5Dv", "campaign":"new_product_annoucement", "channel":"email", "tags":["monday", "test123"], "data":"{\"name\": \"Alex\", \"email\": \"alex@branch.io\", \"user_id\": \"12346\", \"$deeplink_path\": \"article/jan/123\", \"$desktop_url\": \"https://branch.io\"}"}' \
\
https://api.branch.io/v1/url
```

Then I would like to see the status of the Deep Linking URL.

Then I use the following - and it works well for the example provided, but not for our own branch_key with the right campaign and channel.

```
GET https://api.branch.io/v1/url?url=https%3A%2F%2Fbnc.lt%2Fm%2F7IhbRIjjmp&branch_key=key_live_lceUuShIL0u4VHJv8BwEQmaitBfAXqCZ
```

I did change ":", "//" with %3A and %2F.

And Branch Key if for live and test, right?

It returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "The resource you were looking for could not be found."
  }
}
```

Live or test
Do you know why?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do your Branch links begin with bnc.lt, or xxxx.app.links?

Comment: https://xxx.test-app.link/oqa5kI2Htt

Comment: I'm with Branch.io. This is incorrect behavior, and shouldn't be occurring. I will follow up with our engineering team tomorrow and let you know. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.

Comment: Hi I am showcasing this, this week - do you know if there is any progress? Thanks

Comment: It's been confirmed as a bug and it appears there is a solution identified, but I'm afraid I haven't yet heard an ETA for the patch. I will follow up tomorrow and try to get an update for you. Sorry for the delay!

Comment: We have isolated the issue and we have a pull request opened. We’re aiming to have it deployed this week and we’ll let you know as soon as it goes out!

Comment: @ChrisG. this should be fixed now. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Hi Thanks it works.